# mysqli_fetch_array error even when query is valid; running total exports as NULL values

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query which is valid when querying the database:

**EDIT 3:** Per Joe Swindell's advice, it could be that the SET @runningTotal := 0 line in the query. The issue to address is finding a way to convert the complex query below into a JSON string which will also save the the NumPosts part. NumPosts is a running total which is dependent on the SET line; removing the set line removes the mysqli_fetch_array error, but results in NULL for all NumPost values.

**EDIT 2:** I have echoed the query below and pasted back into MySQL to confirm that it is working, and it is in fact valid.

```
SET @runningTotal := 0;
SELECT T.ForDate,  (@runningTotal := @runningTotal + T.DayProgress) as NumPosts
FROM
(

    SELECT DATE(  completed_courses.complete_date ) AS ForDate, COUNT( * ) AS DayProgress
    FROM users
    INNER JOIN completed_courses ON users.user_id = completed_courses.user_id
    INNER JOIN wg_courses ON wg_courses.c_id = completed_courses.c_id
    INNER JOIN workgroup ON wg_courses.wg_id = workgroup.g_id
    WHERE users.course_group LIKE  '4h%' AND completed_courses.complete_date > 0

    GROUP BY DATE(completed_courses.complete_date)
) T
ORDER BY T.ForDate
```

The above outputs:

```
ForDate     NumPosts
2014-07-29  950
2014-07-30  3063
2014-07-31  3669
2014-08-01  4584
2014-08-02  5088
...
```

**EDIT:** Checked the connection and made sure everything matches, and this 
is the output: "Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given"

PHP code:

```
$data = array();
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($con, $result)) {

    $i += 1;
    array_push($data, array($i) + $row);
}
```

Later, the code is encoded into JSON for use in Google Charts:

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>
```

In addition, exporting the query results as SQL, CSV, Excel files, etc. results in all NumPosts values as NULL:

```
ForDate     NumPosts
2014-07-29  NULL
2014-07-30  NULL
2014-07-31  NULL
2014-08-01  NULL
2014-08-02  NULL
...
```

What could be the reason the values are not saving or fetching properly?

Comment: Where is your PHP code? Please add it to the question

Comment: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Your query is failing. Where is the code in php that generates/runs your query?

Comment: Oops, I meant mysqli_fetch_array. Basically, I'm trying to convert a query to JSON for inclusion in Google Charts, but the data is giving a null.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

You are using `mysqli_fetch_array()` incorrectly.

If that is where you are attempting to make your query, you need to do a lot of restructuring. If you've already made your query and stored it in say $result:

You'd use

```
mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

After you've made a connection and query

Your entire code might look something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT Whatever whatever from something;";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);       

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    $i += 1;
    array_push($data, array($i) + $row);
}
```

EDIT: As it stands you have multi query. Run a single query of `SET @runningTotal := 0;`
THEN reset your query variable to the rest of the query and run that, you will then get results.

Comment: or use directly the: `mysqli_fetch_assoc` function.

Comment: I implemented Joe's suggestion, and it gave a boolean error: "mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given". Something here is being evaluated as false...

Comment: That would indicate your query is failing.

Comment: Try putting in an 'echo $query' after you define $query. Copy and paste that echoed query into mysql, see what's going on.

Comment: Yup, I echoed the query right after I defined it and pasted it back into MySQL... it's valid, alright.

Comment: It's your set line. That makes your query a multi query, not a single query.

Comment: So is there any way to convert the multi-query into a JSON string which will also save the the NumPosts part? I'm thinking it's returning false due to the set line.

Answer (score 0):

You have parameter one as your connection, so there may be nothing wrong with your query but the (probably earlier) executed mysqli_connect() fails and returns false (the boolean which is mentioned in your error)

You should go ahead and check that part

Comment: I checked the db connection and made sure the credentials were correct, and got: "Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given".

Comment: You got totaly wrong parameters to your function. Check this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp i recommend to use the assoc result type

Answer (score -2):

You need to rewrite your  `mysqli_fetch_array` as mentioned below and also `array_push` will be rewritten as, **[array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)** manual here.

**Numeric array**

```
    $data = array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row[0],$row[1]);
        array_push($data, $row);
    }
```

**Associative array**

```
    $data = array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

       printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row["ForDate"],$row["NumPosts"]);
       array_push($data, $row);
    }
```

Comment: OOPs, Misunderstand the question.

Comment: delete your answer then :) at least you will get back your 4 points :)